# Pull Partial File Name as Variable

Tags: string, batch-file

I am looking for a short .bat script that can pull a partial file name and set it as a variable. The file names will consistently be the following structure, however there maybe more than 1 files at a time:

> B06XTJ8RX3.MAIN.PC_430.jpg

or

> B06XTJ8RX3.MRG1.PC_430.jpg

While there may be multiple files, the first 10 characters will be the same.

I want to name 'B06XTJ8RX3' as the variable. So far I have only been able to do this by writing the file names up to the first '.' into a text document and then pulling the contents of the text file removing the duplicate strings. All of that seems unnecessary.

```
set images=C:\file_path\images\

for /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%A IN ('dir /b %images%')  do echo %%A >> dupes.txt

type NUL > asins.txt

for /F %%i in ('type dupes.txt ^| sort') Do (

If NOT "!prev!" ==  "%%i" (echo %%i>>asins.txt)
set prev=%%i
)

type NUL > dupes.txt
set prev=5000
```

Does anyone have a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2delims==" %%x in (`set # 2^>nul`) do set "%%x="
set images=C:\file_path\images\

for /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%A IN ('dir /b %images%')  do set /a "#%%A"+=1

set #
```

should report

> #B06XTJ8RX3=2

for the above filenames (#firstelement=occurrences)

The `for /f` in the first line is intended to remove all variables starting `#` from the environment.

With each string detected, increment the count of `#string` found.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2delims==" %%x in (`set # 2^>nul`) do if "%%y" neq 1 echo %%x
```

should report each name with more than 1 file found.

---

If you guarantee that of the n files in the directory, the first 10 chars will all be the same and the 11th will be `.` (and therefore there are no files that do not fit this pattern) then

```
set images=C:\file_path\images\
set /a count=0
for /F "tokens=1 delims=." %%A IN ('dir /b /a-d %images%')  do set "name=%%A"&set/a count+=1

echo the %count% files start "%name%"
```

use the `/a-d` switch to turn off directorynames, should they exist.

- count them as a free bonus.

Comment: I realize my question was missing some information (i made edits). The amount of files will be unknown. However all of the files will have the same first 10 characters. What I would need is a .bat script to simply trim the last 12 characters, leaving my variable=B06XTJ8RX3 in this example.

Comment: beautiful - this final bit works. If you have a minute would you explain how the %name% variable works? Is it a standard variable?

Comment: `name` is not a magic variable name - it could be `zphhrodh6d` if that makes any sense in your application. `dir` delivers a list of the filenames in `/b` (basic) form - name only `/a-d` without directorynames. `FOR/f` analyses the list, `tokens=1` delivers the first token to `%%A` (the specified *metavariable* (tokens=1 is the default and is redundant) and `delims=.` means that the lines are "tokenised" using `.` so the required part of the line (up to the dot) lands up in `%%A`. This is then `set` into a user-variable (name irrelevant) where the quotes delimit the string being assigned.

Comment: Since each name is the same, `name` will first be assigned, then overwritten by the same string until the last iteration of the loop. The `&` concatenates commands, so `count` is incremented for each loop executed=number of matching filenames.

Comment: Thanks for that thorough description @Magoo. It's helpful to be able to read over details like this when receiving assistance!